# adb pull/push is very slow on android emulator

Tags: android, performance, emulation, adb

Has anyone tried to push/pull large files(more than 20MB) to/from an android `Emulator` target? When I did the `adb` push/pull operation, it is ridiculously slow.

The average speed is 75 KB/s. Oh my, that was the speed of my high school network 15 years ago. But the `Emulator` target is just on my hard drive, then why is `adb` push/pull so slow?

Thanks!

Arthur

Answer (score 0):

With a 4.0.3 emulator image, I get transfer speeds of a ~17MB file that are 20-40 times faster than what you cite. Hence, the issue is more of your development environment and not something intrinsic to the Android emulator.

Comment: Thanks Akshay! I am using a 4.1 image on Win7. The ADB version is 1.0.29 and the emulator version is 20.0.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. If I use adb push/pull, it is actually using TCP/IP to connect my PC and the android virtual machine. Now I have found a software that can mount the sdcard.img to a virtual hard drive(I am using Windoze), then everything is fine. The speed of file operations on sdcard.img is as fast as on a real hard drive. The software is named ImDisk.

Arthur